# Is StateSpaceModel command ignoring the StateSpaceRealization option?

Tags: bugs, control-systems

**fixed in 10.0.2**

---

This is version 10.01 on windows. It seems that [StateSpaceModel](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StateSpaceModel.html) is completely ignoring the [StateSpaceRealization](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StateSpaceRealization.html) option when create a state space object.

```
(a = {{0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {-2, -1 , 0, 0}, {1, -1, 0, 0}}) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
(b = {{0}, {0}, {1}, {0}}) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
sys = StateSpaceModel[{a, b}, StateSpaceRealization -> "Controllable"];
(A0 = Normal[sys][[1]]) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Which is the same `A` matrix used as input. This system is controllable:

```
 ControllableModelQ[sys]
 (* True *)
```

so the controllable form is (from any textbook or [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_space_representation)) will have one row (normally the bottom row of `A` but some use the top row) filled up and will have on the entries above the diagonal or below the diagonal, depending on the above). And the matrix `B` will have 1  on the top or botton entry and zero everywhere.

Either way, it is not the same as the input I gave. Here is what I expected `A` to get come out as

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And `B` as

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Not only is the `StateSpaceRealization -> "Controllable"` seems to be not processed, but so is `StateSpaceRealization -> "Observable"`. This also return the state space *not* in the `Observable` form.

fyi, this is how I currently convert `A` to in controllable form (similar to hand calculation)

```
a = {{0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {-2, -1 , 0, 0}, {1, -1, 0, 0}};
aControllable = Table[If[j == i + 1, 1, 0], {i, 4}, {j, 4}];
p = CharacteristicPolynomial[a, s];
c = CoefficientList[p, s];
aControllable[[-1, All]] = -Drop[c, -1];
MatrixForm[aControllable]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug. But I have found a workaround. So I post it here in case someone wants to do this in the future.

The idea is this. Create a state space object first (the `StateSpaceRealization -> "Controllable"` option if used now, will be ignored, hence the bug). Then convert the object to `TransferFunctionModel`. Now create a state space object again, but using the above transfer function mode as input. Now the `StateSpaceRealization -> "Controllable"` option is actually processed and used and the output will be correct.

Here is the example from the question:

```
a = {{0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {-2, -1, 0, 0}, {1, -1, 0, 0}};
b = {{0}, {0}, {1}, {0}};
sys = StateSpaceModel[{a, b}, StateSpaceRealization -> "Controllable"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The above is not the correct Controllable form.

```
tf = TransferFunctionModel[sys];
sys = StateSpaceModel[tf, StateSpaceRealization -> "Controllable"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The above is the correct form. We do not care about the C,D matrices for the controllable form. Only A,B is what matters and they are correct now.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in version 10.0.2

```
a = {{0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {-2, -1, 0, 0}, {1, -1, 0, 0}}
b = {{0}, {0}, {1}, {0}}
sys = StateSpaceModel[{a, b}, StateSpaceRealization -> "Controllable"];
(A0 = Normal[sys][[1]]) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]